# Find the line tangent to the parametric curve $\left\langle t^3-1,t^4+1,t \right\rangle$

Tags: derivatives, parametric

Firstly, this is a homework problem, so I would appreciate it if you might not just write the answer and rather, if I am wrong, provide suggestions only.

I am given a parametric curve with the components
\begin{align}
\begin{matrix}
x=t^3-1,\\y=t^4+1, \\z=t,
\end{matrix}
\end{align}
and I must find the tangent line (parametrically) to this curve at the point $\left(0,2,1\right)$. Since $t=1$ gives us this coordinate, I have found that
\begin{align}
\begin{matrix}
x'\left(1\right)=3\left(1\right)^2=3,\\y'\left(1\right)=4\left(1\right)^3=4,\\z'\left(1\right)=1,
\end{matrix}
\end{align}
and thus in using the point-slope form of a line in each of the components I have arrived at the parametric line
\begin{align}
\begin{matrix}
x=3\left(t-1\right)=3t-3,\\y=4\left(t-1\right)+2=4t-2,\\z=1\left(t-1\right)+1=t.
\end{matrix}
\end{align}
Am I correct? And additionally, I want it to be known that I realize it is not your job to do my homework. I'm just hoping to see where I may have gone wrong.

Comment: @BaronVT Because that simplifies to $z=t$ I found, so I did not write it. I will add it, however, for the sake of completeness in my answer.

Comment: I think in an older edit, it said $z = 1$, this is what I was reacting to. In any event, I have no disagreement with the current incarnation.

Comment: You method and answer appear correct.